# Oracle Apex app-icon set when creating app is not the correct one

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Apex 19.2 to create different new applications and every time I would like to use a different icon. The theme default is a blu graph and in the wizard I can change the icon and the color, e.g. I can set a green folder.

In some case the correct icon is not shown and the default one in used.

From shared components -> static application files I download app-icon.css and app-icon.svg and the svg is the correct one.

Comment: I have seen this behavior too, I assume it is a bug caused by browser caching. Try creating your apps in incognito mode (have not tried that myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check in different latest browsers to reproduce the issue and if its consistent across. Try deleting your browser history and restart your browser as well to see if that fixes the issue.